# Remove public from url on shared hosting in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-8, laravel-7

I have hosted Laravel 8 application in sub folder

Inside public_html folder have created subfolder with `project_name`

and when i access it

> https://maindomain.in/project_name

it

redirects to `https://maindomain.in/public/project_name`

I have checked these links

> 1. [Laravel 7.x - How to remove 'public' from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61806001/laravel-7-x-how-to-remove-public-from-url)
> 2. [Remove public from URL Laravel 5.3 on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158002/remove-public-from-url-laravel-5-3-on-shared-hosting)

tried changing `.htaccess` and renaming `server.php` to `index.php` but can only access site through

`https://maindomain.in/project_name/public` this url.

It only reads `.htaccess` of public directory.

`htaccess of root directory`

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.css|.js|.png|.jpg|.gif|robots.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Any solution. Thanks

Comment: I have an answer in a post with mainly the same issue, many people tried my structure and worked for them, checking this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71387680/16101788 it talks about structuring a laravel  project in a server. In any case, the public folder was added to the url.

Comment: @Guille Thanks will placing `index.php` file inside public folder will cause issue? i have already one `index.php` file for other application inside public_html folder

Comment: Yes it will, as i said maybe you need to change the `bootstrap.php` and `autoload.php` access paths to make the app work. As an example in your `require __DIR__ . '/../../laravel-app/vendor/autoload.php';` use the `../..` as many times as you need to match your app logic.

Comment: @Guille Is there any solution so that `index.php` of root folder which is already there should not be affected?

Answer (score 0):

the most perfect way to do this is by moving all your laravel files outside `public_html` after that move all your files from `public` folder to `public_html`

then go to `\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` and add the following lines to the `register()` method

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path('public_html');
});
```

keep the other settings like `.htaccess` without change

I hope it's helpful